# Comparing entries in correlation matrices

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho

I am trying to compare entries in a 10x10 Spearman correlation matrix to determine whether one entry is closer to another entry than it is to a third entry.

The caveat is that I actually have 1000 of these correlation matrices, not one, and the matrices are not statistically independent.

To give some background: I have 1000 molecules and 10 ways of comparing them.
Each row and column in the matrices correspond to one of the ways of comparing the molecules and row-column pair is the correlation between the comparison methods.
Each matrix corresponds to one molecule being compared to all the other molecules, so each cell in that matrix corresponds to comparing two methods using that molecule as a reference against the 1000 molecules.

If I had one matrix, I would have converted the entries using Fisher's Z transformation the way it was done here:
[Comparing correlation coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12558/comparing-correlation-coefficients)

With multiple matrices, should I

a) Take a mean of each of the cells (spearman's coeficients) across the 1000 matrices and then perform the transformation on the matrix of the means?
or
b) First perform the Fisher's Z transformation on all cells in every matrix, then take a mean of the cells over 1000 matrices and use the new matrix of means of Fisher's Z transformations for comparisons?

c) Something else?

Edit1:

So far I have this:
[image: Comparing two molecular similarity methods]

The bottom left histogram corresponds to a histogram of Spearman correlations between two comparison methods, where each molecule is picked as a reference.  Hence, there are 1000 points in the histogram.

If I picked just one molecule as a reference to produce one matrix, I wouldn't know which one it is best to pick and why I should ignore others.

Edit2:

Can I just treat them as populations of tau and rho coefficients and say that the mean of one population is significantly larger or smaller than the mean of another population?
In other words, have 10 populations of 1000 members each and try to determine whether any are significantly larger or smaller than others?

Comment: What is your ultimate study objective?  (Stopping with the comparisons of correlation coefficients does not appear to have any scientific meaning or practical use: what is the *aim* of those comparisons?)

Comment: That's a lot of pairwise correlations, you will probably have a large number of spurious ones.

Comment: Let's say there are three ways of comparing molecules, numbered 1-3  (where each method determines how close each of the 1000 molecules is to the reference).  Additionally I am picking each of the 1000 molecules as a reference, hence 1000 matrices.  I am interested in determining whether the first way is closer to the second way than it is to the third way, and if the second and the third ways are closer to each other than they are to the first way.  In essence, I am trying to cluster the comparisons by similarity.  The final goal is to find where my comparison method is in this cluster.

Comment: Then it seems you should be examining a single 3 by 3 (or actually, 10 by 10) matrix, not 1000 of them!

Comment: Then I would be picking one molecule as a reference.  Are you saying it doesn't make sense to pick every molecule as a reference?  The similarity between comparisons is a little different depending on which molecule is used as a reference.