# Following Pearson correlation analysis how to compare subsets of the significant correlations

Tags: r, correlation, pearson-r, subset

**How can I statistically compare subsets of the significant correlations produced from Pearson correlation analysis (*r*-value, *p*-value) and Benjamini-Hochberg multiple testing adjustment (*q*-value)?**

To help illustrate my question, here's an example:

1. Pairwise correlations are calculated from continuous data for 26 variables `A` through `Z`.
2. How can I test whether the resultant significant correlations in the subset of `A` with each of the vowels `E`, `I`, `O`, `U` are more correlated than in the subset `A` with each of the remaining consonants?

I don't know if any of the following approaches may be appropriate: hierarchical cluster analysis, principal component analysis, permutation testing, or some form of network analysis?

**Edit:** [Comparing correlation coefficients](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12558/332718) suggests Fisher's z-transform method. However, I am unsure whether this is possible for comparing groups of correlations (not 2 individual correlations). If it is possible how can I achieve this in R?

I appreciate any help offered in pointing me in the right direction.
I have experience in **R** and welcome examples.

Comment: This depends on the error of your calculated correlations.

Comment: @frank thank you, are you able to expand? In R `cor.test` doesn't provide a result that I'm able to identify as being the error of the correlations. I have _r_-values from `cor.test` and _q_-values from `p.adjust(method = "BH")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that the following question is the same as mine: [How to Test the Difference between 2 Sets of Pearson Correlations?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61456/332718), and this answer is what I was after: [Fisher z-transformation of Pearson r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/368095/332718)